# How to delete a version in tradingview pine

Tags: pine-script

I have been changing my tradingview pine code, when I save it, tradingview creates a version.
Now I am getting confused with so many version. I want to delete the older version. How can I do that in tradingview.

Thanks,
Shyam

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can delete the version history.
You could save the version you need as a new script, and then delete the old script.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to make parallel system for version control I guess.